# How to setup JNDI lookup in a Spring-JUnit test?

Tags: spring, junit, jndi, initial-context

I'm using Maven 3.0.3, Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE, and JUnit 4.8.1.  How do I create JNDI functionality outside the container (which in my case would be JBoss)?  I thought Spring's jndiTemplate would do the trick (from my testApplicationContext.xml file):

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">localhost:1099</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>

...

<!-- Can't change the below code -->
<bean class="org.springframework.ejb.access.SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean" lazy-init="true" singleton="true" id="skillManager">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>customLibSkillManager</value>
    </property>
    <property name="businessInterface">
        <value>customLibx.skills.customLibSkillManager_IF</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But when I run my JUnit test, I get this exception …

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'skillsValidationManager' defined in class path resource [_module_config/managers/proxies.remote.COMMON.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:645)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:325)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
    at org.springframework.ejb.access.AbstractRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor.lookup(AbstractRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.springframework.ejb.access.AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.refreshHome(AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.ejb.access.SimpleRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor.refreshHome(SimpleRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.springframework.ejb.access.AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.ejb.access.SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean.java:100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 65 more
```

I setup my JUnit yes like so …

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "file:src/test/resources/testApplicationContext.xml" })
public class StandardsParserServiceTest extends AbstractCorrelationsTest {
```

Comment: would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940895/how-to-test-a-mocked-jndi-datasource-with-spring

Comment: Could you show us more, may be how you are getting this `JndiTemplate` and how you are using it in your test ?

Comment: Have you tried to use  PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer with these two properties specified?