# How to run JUnit Test in Spring Injecting JBOSS JNDI datasources

Tags: java, spring, junit, jboss, jndi

I have an application in spring with database oracle running on JBOSS 7.1.
I want to test my service layer beans simply running a junit test.
In my spring context I use a jndi datasource like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jboss/datasources/myDatasource" />
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

When I run my junit test that loads the spring context test I receive an exception like:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
```

How can I inject the JNDI datasource in my tests without change my context in jboss?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746939/how-to-setup-jndi-lookup-in-a-spring-junit-test?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961815/cannot-instantiate-class-org-apache-naming-java-javaurlcontextfactory) post, or [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2409281) great blog post I found three ways to solve my issue, just create BeforeClass method in your JUnitTest Class.

I post it for the community:

**- Solution 1**
This solution, requires the catalina.jar and the oracledriver in your classpath:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    try {
        System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
        System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.apache.naming");            
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();

        ic.createSubcontext("jboss");
        ic.createSubcontext("jboss/datasources");
        ic.createSubcontext("jboss/datasources/myDatasource");

        OracleConnectionPoolDataSource ds = new OracleConnectionPoolDataSource();
        ds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxx:1521:xxxxx");
        ds.setUser("myUserid");
        ds.setPassword("myPass");

        ic.rebind("jboss/datasources/myDatasource", ds);
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

if you use maven you can put in your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>catalina</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.37</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**- Solution 2**
This solution, requires commons-dbcp in your classpath:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpDataSource() throws Exception {
    try {
        SimpleNamingContextBuilder builder = new SimpleNamingContextBuilder();
        DriverAdapterCPDS cpds = new DriverAdapterCPDS();
        cpds.setDriver("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        cpds.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxx:1521:xxxxx");
        cpds.setUser("myUsername");
        cpds.setPassword("myPass");

        SharedPoolDataSource dataSource = new SharedPoolDataSource();
        dataSource.setConnectionPoolDataSource(cpds);
        dataSource.setMaxActive(10);
        dataSource.setMaxWait(50);
        builder.bind("jboss/datasources/myDatasource", dataSource);
        builder.activate();
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

in your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**- Solution 3**
This solution uses the OracleConnectionPoolDataSource included in Oracle Driver:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpDataSource() throws Exception {
    try {
        SimpleNamingContextBuilder builder = new SimpleNamingContextBuilder();

        OracleConnectionPoolDataSource ds = new OracleConnectionPoolDataSource();
        ds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxx:1521:xxxxx");
        ds.setUser("myUsername");
        ds.setPassword("myPass");           

        builder.bind("jboss/datasources/myDatasource", ds);
        builder.activate();
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is possible to create JNDIs loading them from -ds.xml configuration files (with the datasources tag inside of them). Can you give or point some example? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to separate out the "infrastructure" configuration (`DataSource`, `PlatformTransactionManager`, …) and use JNDI / JTA only when deployed in WildFly and a different configuration for testing. You can either use Spring conditional beans for this or build your application context differently.