# Programatically set InitialContext for unit test

Tags: java, jersey, jndi, junit4

I'm using a `Resource` tag in tomcat's `context.xml` file to store database connection info. I access it in my jersey servlet like this:

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup(DB_SOURCE_CONTEXT);
return ds.getConnection();
```

For unit testing, I'm using jersey-test and grizzly2, rather than deploying to tomcat. I'm trying to set the connection properties to use a test DB (currently MySQL, but I will change it to DBUnit next) in the unit test class:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void initializeTest() throws NamingException
{
  Context initContext = new InitialContext();
  Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
  BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
  dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  dataSource.setUsername("root");
  dataSource.setPassword("");
  dataSource.setUrl(TEST_DB_URL);
  dataSource.setMaxTotal(10);
  dataSource.setMaxIdle(5);
  dataSource.setInitialSize(5);
  dataSource.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
  envContext.bind(DB_SOURCE_CONTEXT, dataSource);
}
```

But I get the following exception, so it's clearly not the correct way to do it:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or
system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:
java.naming.factory.initial
```

How can I set these values so the Context reading code in the servlet reads the test values?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545129/setting-up-jndi-datasource-in-junit

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue when using glassfish and creating a context for testing.

You need to provide some properties for the InitialContext so that it can build itself correctly.

For example:

```
Hashtable<String, String> props = new Hashtable<>();
props.put("java.naming.factory.initial","com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory");
props.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
props.put("java.naming.factory.state","com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
```

Hope this helps.