# How do you test a spring jdbcTemplate with JUNIT?

Tags: java, spring, junit, datasource, jdbctemplate

I have a DAO that I'm trying to test that uses a jdbcTemplate.  The spring jdbcTemplate has a datasoruce attribute on it that needs to be set for it to work.  However, when a JUNIT test runs the datasource does not exist and the bean creation fails.  How can I set up the datasource of the jdbcTemplate to work in the JUNIT test case?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'thisDatasource' defined in class path resource [userDataBaseContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:645)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:325)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 40 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem using information from the following link:

[How to test a mocked JNDI datasource with Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940895/how-to-test-a-mocked-jndi-datasource-with-spring)

Instead of using the datasource defined in my spring files, I just created a new datasource:

```
<bean id="thisDatasource"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
p:driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
p:url="jdbc:sqlserver://sqlserver:1234;databaseName=myTables"
p:username="userid"
p:password="passw0rd" /> 


<bean id="databaseUserDAOTest" 
class="com.spring.security.custom.user.detail.DatabaseUserDAO" >
<!-- Inject the datasource of the jdbcTemplate -->
<property name="dataSource" ref="thisDatasource" />        
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Spring Testing Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html).  It allows your unit test to leverage a Spring Container configured for your application-context.  Once setup you can use @Autowired on your datasource to inject the datasource required to test the jdbcTemplate.

Here is an example of one of my test using Spring-Data.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.tothought.entities.Post;
import org.tothought.entities.PostPart;
import org.tothought.entities.Tag;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@Transactional
public class PostRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired 
    TagRepository tagRepository;

    @Test
    public void findOneTest() {
        Post post = repository.findOne(1);
        assertNotNull(post);
        assertTrue(post.getTags().size()>1);
    }
}
```

Notice the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation.  This annotation points to the context used to setup the Spring container, which I then inject my repository from.  Since I have not specified a name for my context Spring searches for a configuration file within the same directory as my test class that has the name PostRepositoryTest-context.xml.  This setup is described in more detail in the documentation provided above.

To begin using the project include the following in your pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detail on the Spring Testing framework.  I think I have everything to the point of "injecting" the datasource.  The issue I'm having is that because I'm running a JUnit test, the datasource does not exist.  A datasource is a server side element and a Junit test runs outside of the server.  A better question might be, how do you fake a datasource to use in a Junit test for a JDBCTemplate